# Printing A-Z using putchar() with tolower() or toupper() stops the loop at the first char

Tags: c

Trying to iterate through ASCII characters

I want to print all the **A-Z** characters in lowercase but I get only the first char printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++)
    {
        x = tolower(x);
        putchar(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the line

```
x = tolower(x);
```

After the first iteration, it overrides **`x`** to a bigger value (because the codes of lowercase characters are bigger than uppercase characters), thus the loop doesn't continue any further.

```
int x = 'A' // 65
```

**`A`** is equivalent to **65**.

```
x <= 'Z' // 90
```

**`Z`** is equivalent to **90**.

### 1st Iteration:

The expression `x <= 'Z'` or `'A' <= 'Z'` is the same as `65 <= 90` which is **true**.

But then the line

```
x = tolower(x);
```

**Overrides** **`x`** from `'A'` (65) to `'a'` (97)

So, after printing the first char which is `'a'`, the loop increments `97` (=> `98`) then iterates again

### 2nd Iteration:

Is `x <= 'Z'` which is `98 <= 90`? No. That's **false**. Therefore the loop breaks.

To fix this, you need to not override the variable which the loop depends on to continue execution. Try storing the lowercase result in another variable other that `x`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++) // jumps from 'A'(65) to 'B'(66) to ... in order.
    {
        char small = tolower(x);
        putchar(small);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or you could also just print the return value right away `putchar(tolower(x));`

Comment: The problem I see with the `for(int x = 'A'; x <= 'z'; x++) `solution is that `x` jumps from `A` to `b`. While the result might be the same, it is only a coincidence and only works because of the way the ASCII was designed. Change the problem slightly (like I did on my answer), and you'll see that you get wrong results. For me, the only viable solution is the last one: **don't alter the running variable in the code block** (unless it's necessary by the algorithm).

Comment: It does fix **this** problem. I know exactly what you mean but it has nothing to do with printing A-Z in lowercase since ***both*** ways that are posted in this answer would work efficiently to achieve it. by the way, If you looked at the 2nd method, It doesn't change x. So it'd jump from `A` to `B` in order.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that your are modifying the variable that is
used as the running variable for the loop.

Take a look at the [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) and you'll notice that the upper case
letters have an integer value smaller than the lower case letters.

So in the first iteration, `x` is assigned to `A`, then you do

```
x = tolower(x);
```

which changes the value of `x` from `A` to `a`. The integer value of `a` is 97,
which is greater than the integer value of `Z` (which is 90). When the next
iteration is started `x++` is executed, which make `x` even larger than 90, so the condition

```
x <= 'Z'
```

will be evaluated to false, hence the loop stops.

So, don't change the variable that your are using as the running variable for the
loop. You can do either

```
for(int x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++)
{
    int lower_x = tolower(x);
    putchar(lower_x);
}
```

or

```
for(int x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++)
{
    putchar(tolower(x));
}
```

In both cases `x` is only modified by the loop itself and you don't run into
the problem you've had.

Note that while

```
int main()
{
    for(int x = 'A'; x <= 'z'; x++) // Notice (x <= 'Z') > > (x <= 'z')
    {
        x = tolower(x);
        putchar(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gives you the same results in this case, this is not in general the correct
solution, because it is still modifying the `x` variable outside the
loop-construct. The values of `x`
will be

- *First iteration* `x == 'A'`
- *Second iteration* `x == 'b'`
- *Third iteration* `x == 'c'`
- ...

Like I said, the end result might the same, but this is only a coincidence. Image
you have this task: *print the values multiplied by 100 from 10 to 20*

If you do

```
for(int x = 10; x <= 20; x++)
{
    x = x * 100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

You will have the same situation as before. But the solution

```
for(int x = 10; x <= 200; x++)
{
    x = x * 100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

would print completely incorrect values. Like for your problem, the correct
solution would be **not to modify** `x` in the block

```
for(int x = 10; x <= 20; x++)
{
    printf("%d\n", x * 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do note that the `for` loop

```
for(int x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++)
{
    x = tolower(x);
    putchar(x);
}
```

is just syntactic sugar for a `while` loop - here equivalent to

```
{
    int x = 'A';
    while (x <= 'Z') {
        x = tolower(x);
        putchar(x);
        x ++;
    }
}
```

By the time it reaches the `x ++`, the value  is `'a'` i.e. 97, and after the increment, it will be `'b'` i.e. 98. Since `'b' <= 'Z'` (98 <= 90) is false, the iteration stops.

Many newcomers to C think `for` is some magical structure, as it is in some other programming languages, and that's where they go wrong.

P.s. had you written `putchar(tolower(x));` your program would have worked.

Comment: I'm not a beginner, I just wanted to share the answer with C newbies if they got stuck as a community wiki, by the way, very nice strategy. :)